# How to make a recovery partition on a ubuntu laptop?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, data-recovery, intel

I have been wondering, how to make a recovery partition, such as System76 does with its Ubuntu laptops:

> There isn’t an included recovery disc you can run off of in case your
>   system gets messed up. Instead, there’s a recovery partition you can
>   boot into to start a full recovery.
>   [Source](http://rexofcyber.blogspot.com/2012/10/system76-gazelle-professional-laptop.html)

How do they make those? Is it simply a copy of system when first installed? How can I make a recovery partition fo my own?